# Convert date to nvarchar and merge two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have two columns in date format:

```
Column_1: [2014-12-19]
Column_2: [2015-08-31]
```

I want to merge them and change the the data type to `NVARCHAR`.

I tried this code

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[ Column_1])+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[Column_2])AS TEST
```

but I get this result:

```
2014-12-192015-08-31
```

instead of `2014121920150831` without the hyphens.

Could you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can fiddle around with conversion codes, just use replace:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), Column_1) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), Column_2), '-', '') AS TEST
```

Or, if you don't want to be dependent on the local date format:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), Column_1, 112) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), Column_2, 112) AS TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

`CONVERT` has a third parameter which determines the format of the date/time. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for definition. Code 112 will give you what you want.

You can also use `REPLACE` to remove the hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @date1 date = '2014-12-19',
        @date2 date = '2015-08-31'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @date1, 112)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @date2, 112)
```